# Immutable.js add new data

Tags: immutable.js

I want to save all the searches from the user as a key of objects (search field):

```
  beforeState = fromJS({
      showFilter: false,
      loading: false,
      error: false,
      search: fromJS({})
    })

  afterState = fromJS({
      showFilter: false,
      loading: false,
      error: false,
      search: 
         key1: [{}, {},...],
         key2: [{}, {}, {}...]
})
```

New data:

```
const searchText = 'test'
const data = [{object1}, {object2},....]

const expectedResult = state
```

search has to be immutable as it can change. key1, key2... doesn't need to, as once they're initilised won't change.

Two questions:

I think I need fromJS function in searchKey in order to get a map, I mean, fromJS function does not nest maps

```
var t = beforeState.get('search').constructor.name; 
console.log(t) //gets Map but without fromJS gets Object
```

But as array inside key1, key2, can't mutate, another fromJS would't be needed. Is it that way?

How can I insert key1, key2.. values inside search field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mergeDeep, seems to be ok:

```
var boxes = Immutable.fromJS({
  box1: {
    id:1
  },
  box2: {
    id:2
  },
  search: Immutable.fromJS({box3: {z:7}})
});

var data = Immutable.fromJS({
  search: {
      box3: {id:3}
  }
});


var newBoxes = boxes.mergeDeep(data);
console.log(newBoxes.get('search').toJS());
```